# What should i put when setting the attribute in JavaScript on setAttribute() when it comes to text to create a sequence of changing text?

Tags: javascript, html

Am making my portfolio and want to create a sequence of changing of text using vanilla java script but does not work because i do not know what to put on setAttribute() first argument

Tried to put the id name, adding the source on the text tag and then trying to put the source there

```
function changeImage(){
    myImage.setAttribute('#bold', arrayImage[arrayIndex]);

    arrayIndex++;

    if (arrayIndex >= arrayImage.length) {
        arrayIndex=0;
    }
}

setInterval(changeImage,3000);
```

No error message but after 3 seconds the text was supposed to be changing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: really unclear  what you are trying to do with an attribute.... What is in arrayImage exactly?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the src attribute of myImage? e.g myImage.setAttribute('src', arrayImage[arrayIndex]), by the way you are talking about "text", so maybe you've to share a little bit more about your thoughts.